# Next cloud and mysql setup: authentication method unknown to the client

Tags: mysql, docker, azure-aks, rancher, nextcloud

Using the rancher GUI, I'm trying to set up Nextcloud with MySQL database workloads on my AKS cluster. In the environment variables, I already have defined the admin user and password so why do I get this error on the create admin page?

> Error while trying to create admin user: Failed to connect to the
> database: An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The
> server requested authentication method unknown to the client

I entered the Username and password correctly multiple times.
Below are my configurations for the database and nextcloud so far.

**database workload:**

```
Name: nextdb
Docker image: mysql
port: not set
```

I have the following variables:

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassX 
MYSQL_DATABASE=nextDB
MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
MYSQL_PASSWORD=passX
```

- volumes configuration:

> Volume Type: Bind-Mount
>
> Volume Name: nextdb
>
> Path on the Node : /nextdb
>
> The Path on the Node must be: a directory or create
>
> Mount Point: /var/lib/mysql

**nextcloud workload:**

- Name: nextcloud
- Docker Image: nextcloud
- Port Mapping:

  Port Name : nextcloud80
  Publish the container port: 80
  Protocol: TCP
  As a: Layer-4 load balancer
  On listening port: 80
- Environment variables:

  MYSQL_DATABASE=nextDB

  MYSQL_USER=nextcloud

  MYSQL_PASSWORD=passX

  MYSQL_HOST=nextdb

  NEXTCLOUD_ADMIN_USER=admin

  NEXTCLOUD_ADMIN_PASSWORD=adminPass

  NEXTCLOUD_DATA_DIR=/var/www/html/nextcloud
- Volumes:

Volume 1:

```
name: nextcloud
Volume Type: Bind-Mount
Path on the Node: /nextcloud
The Path on the Node must be: a directory or create.
Mount Point: /var/www/html
```

**Volume 2**

```
name: nextdb
Volume Type: Bind-Mount
Path on the Node: /nextdatabase
The Path on the Node must be: a directory or create.
Mount Point: /var/lib/mysql
```

What are the problems with my configurations?

Comment: you have probably a mysql 8 server and you need as default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password in your my.conf file

Answer (score 0):

Starting with version 8.02, MySQL updated the default authentication method for client connections. To revert to the older authentication method you need to explicitly specify the default authentication method.

If you are able to update your DB service in Rancher to pass the container argument `--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password` that should revert MySQL to the older auth method.

Alternatively, depending on the MySQL image you are using, you can create a new Docker image from that base which replaces `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` inside the container. You should inspect `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` before you replace it, if there are any `!includedir` directives in the config file, you can place your supplemental configuration into an included folder using whatever filename you choose.

The supplemental configuration should look like this:

```
[mysqld]
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
```